# How to start the snmpd with other options to get less log messages?

Tags: snmp

My Linux system works with Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

A "ps -ef | grep snmpd" gives:
Debian-+   851     1  0 Apr01 ?        00:01:20 /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux mteTrigger mteTriggerConf -f

The file /var/log/syslog is full of notifications like:
Apr  4 11:14:14 system2 snmpd[851]: Connection from UDP: [192.168.0.238]:35386->[192.168.0.7]:161

The file /etc/default/snmpd contains:
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid'

To get less notifications in the file /var/log/syslog, I changed this file to:
SNMPDOPTS='-LSwd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid'

After restarting the snmpd with "systemctl restart snmpd.service", a "systemctl status snmpd.service" show that the snmpd is really restarted.

But a "ps -ef | grep snmpd" still shows the option "Lsd" instead of "LSwd".

Also after a "systemctl daemon-reload".

How can I start the snmpd with the "LSwd" option to get less logging?

Comment: Hello. What does this statement from your question mean? <My Linux system works with Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS> Is it Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: All the snmpd tags. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/snmpd.htm

Comment: The command 'cat /etc/issue' on my Ubuntu Linux system give "Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS'